# cv2 findChessboardCorner accuracy is low when using Raspberry Pi camera module

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, camera-calibration, opencv

I am trying to calibrate two cameras for stereo vision. One is Pi Camera and the other is a USB webcam plugged in Raspberry Pi. I don't know why, but the chessboard points found by Pi are less accurate (always). Please look at the picture attached. The right one (webcam) is more straight and accurate. Would there be any way to improve this?

[image]

Here are some parts of the script.

```
# webcam is called by cv2.VideoCapture, and picam is called by PiCamera()
left = PiCamera()
left.resolution = (640,480)
right = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while n <= Total_num:

    right.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
    right.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

    img1 = np.empty((480, 640, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    left.capture(img1, "bgr")
    ret, img2 = right.read()
```

after this, they are turned into gray, and the corners are found.

```
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret1, corners1 = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray1, checkerBoard, None)
ret2, corners2 = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray2, checkerBoard, None)

cv2.cornerSubPix(gray1, corners1, (5, 5), (-1, -1), criteria)
cv2.cornerSubPix(gray2, corners1, (5, 5), (-1, -1), criteria)

cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img1, checkerBoard, corners1, ret1)
cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img2, checkerBoard, corners2, ret2)
```

Comment: Do you use the Raspberry Pi only to gather the images or the is this script run there?

Comment: The lefthand image is more angled and the squares appear smaller than the righthand - have you tried correcting this so the source is more similar? Is the native resolution (pixels and colour depth) of the webcam much better than the Pi Camera? Lighting difference? Lens specification? Exposure?

Comment: @ Fred Guth: Both. I gathered images using the Raspberry Pi and run the script above.

Comment: @barny I tried with different angles, but the webcam catches the points perfectly even when it is tilted while picam does not. The native resolution I think is actually better with picam or similar. The reason I think is that when I implement another script that 1. takes pictures and save them first. 2. loads those images and finds points. This one shows good results for both of them. I don't quite understand why the two scripts show different performance

Comment: Maybe the picam is taking a frame from a video rather than a complete picture, and that affects the image quality.